# Best practice for S3 folder names linked to users

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

I am uploading PDF's to an s3 bucket that are linked to user sessions. I am currently uploading using their email address as the folder name so it's human and machine readable. I could use the Mongo user ID as well.

A hypothetical example:

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/test%40test.com/598ffb55r4233f001152f9f4/File.pdf

The '@' in 'test@test.com' get's interpreted as '%40'.

What' best practice in this case? I know Amazon regard '@' as a character that needs special handling. I've come across no issues yet.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: Do you _need_ it to be human-readable? Why?

Comment: So, what's the problem? %40 is url-encoded @. RFC 3986 is not Amazon-specific.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in the back-end world and I am in an early stage startup so it's a 'just in case' thing for me as there will be some human work at first. Are UID's normally used for this sort of thing? I don't want to use email addresses as a folder name if it will cause issues in the future.

Comment: Email is a bad idea, because I do change my email in sites at times. You should link it with the mongo ID only

Comment: Makes sense Tarun cheers! Seems obvious now.